# Hover Effect in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to change the styling of my links present on navbar when hovered such as text color background how can I do that in React. Have attached the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAMdR.png)

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
      <Navbar light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand href="/"><img src="assets/Yuvaa_Logo.png"></img></NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav  navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="#"><span style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"black"}}>Home</span></NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="#"><span style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"black"}}>About US</span></NavLink>

            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target hovering in react similarly to how you would do it in JS. The easiest way would be on you css styling, whether it's a separete file or a react styling package like styled-components:

```
.given-class:hover {
 color: red;
}
```

You could also target it with with javascript if needed:

```
document.getElementById("link-id").onmouseover = function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

A more "react" way of doing it but quite advanced would be to take advantage of the useref() hook to target the specific link. But that would be quite an overkill.

Unless you need very specific functionality your best option is to go with the first option and target the element in your css.